# How do I setup a node with to-do tasks?

Tags: views, nodes, entities, 8

I am looking to build a Drupal 8 website that requires the notion of a content type (a job) that has fields for adding tasks that can be assigned a due date and be ticket off when completed.

Then I'll need to be able to show all the tasks on a calendar view, overdue reminders, repeat tasks etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I could approach configuring this with core functionality or modules for Drupal 8?

Sincerely,

Andy

Comment: You have to create a new field type with status(bool), weight(int), title(string) and date(timestamp) + add your own field formatter. If you're looking for a module, I can't help.

Comment: @IvanJaros thank you but I'm not really clear on the finer details of your suggested solution.

I assume "status" will be for whether the task is active/overdue/complete?

I've got no idea what the "weight" field is for?

No idea what a field formatter is?

Comment: In that case you are probably looking for ready made solution(module) which I do not know of any so maybe someone else can suggest one.

Comment: [casetracker](https://www.drupal.org/node/2560519) is the turnkey solution, but still needs to be completed for Drupla 8.